# Uniqueness of series representation. (Complex Analysis).

Tags: complex-analysis

***Theorem*** : If a series $$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (z-z_0)^{n}$$

converges to $f(z)$ at all points interior to some circle $|z-z_0| = R$ , then it is the taylor series expansion for $f$ in powers of $z-z_0$.

(1) First we write the series by changing the index as : $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m (z-z_0)^{m}$$

(2) Now we make use of another theorem ( I don't want to get into that , just accepting its result and writing the following) : $$\int_{C}g(z)f(z)dz = \sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m \int_{C}g(z)(z-z_0)^{m}dz$$

where $g(z) = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i}\cdot \dfrac{1}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}$ and $C$ is some circle centered at $z_0$ and with radius less than $R$.

(3) Next we prove that : $$\int_{C}g(z)f(z)dz = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i}\cdot \int_{C}\dfrac{f(z)dz}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}} = \dfrac{ f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!}$$

I was able to prove it using the extension of Cauchy Integral formula. So we move to next step.

(4) Now we prove that : $$\int_{C}g(z)(z-z_0)^{m}dz = \dfrac{1}{2 \pi i}\cdot \int_{C}\dfrac{dz}{(z-z_0)^{n-m+1}} =  \begin{cases} 
      0 ,\: \: when \:\: m \neq n \\
      1 ,\: \: when \:\: m=n \\ 
\end{cases} $$

I was able to prove this too.. Now my problem arises in the next step..

(5) Now this step says , " it is clear that " : $$\sum_{m=0}^\infty a_m \int_{C}g(z)(z-z_0)^{m}dz = a_n$$ ,

How can we write this ?

If we take $\int_{C}g(z)(z-z_0)^{m}dz = 1$ (say) , then ,

$\dfrac{ f^{(n)}(z_0)}{n!} = \sum_{m=0}^{\infty}a_m \cdot 1$ ,

How can we write step (5) , could anyone help ?

P.S : I know its a long proof , but please , bear with me.. !!

Comment: (4) makes no sense. It cannot have different values depending on $n$?

Comment: I guess that is included in the case $ m \neq n$ , we consider 2 cases , m>n & n>m , in both the cases the result will come out to be zero..@copper.hat

Comment: My comment above is wrong. It does make sense, the $n$ comes from the definition of $g$. I have added an answer below, hopefully that explains the above.

Comment: Can we not just differentiate the power series k times and evaluate at z0 to get the ak coefficient? Why the need for this more complicated proof? Unless I am missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From (2) you have
${1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_C {1 \over (z-z_0)^{n+1}} f(z)dz = {1 \over 2 \pi i}\sum_m a_m \int_C {(z-z_0)^m \over (z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz $, and with (4) you have shown that
${1 \over 2 \pi i} \int_C {(z-z_0)^m \over (z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz = \delta_{mn}$, where $\delta_{mn} = \begin{cases} 1 , & m=n\\
0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$. So, now substitute this result into the first
to get
${1 \over 2 \pi i}\sum_m a_m \int_C {(z-z_0)^m \over (z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz = \sum_m a_m \delta_{mn} = a_n$.

The combining this with the result from (3) gives
$\int_C g(z)f(z)dz = a_n = {1 \over n!} f^{(n)}(z_0)$.

Comment: In the summation, $n$ is fixed. You are summing over $m$, and the only value of $m$ for which $\delta_{mn} = 1$ is $m=n$. Hence you have $a_0 \cdot 0 + a_1\cdot 0 + \cdots + a_{n-1} \cdot 0 + a_n \cdot 1 + a_{n+1} \cdot 0 + \cdots$.

Comment: Got it.. Thanks a lot !
And sorry for bothering you this much.. :P

Comment: Glad to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Look at what step four tells you about when that integral is zero/non-zero and think about how that will affect the sum in step five.

Comment: Still , I am not getting it..
Could you please elaborate a little bit ?

Comment: So, when you look at the sum on the left-hand side for part five, what happens when m = n and m /= n?

Comment: When , $m \neq n$ it's zero , but when $m=n$ it's $\sum a_m$ , so how can we write that equal to $a_n$ ?

Comment: But, when m = n, we're just dealing with one term of the sum. Since everything else is zero, then the entire sum is equal to that one term (which is a_n * integral_n). Since integral_n = 1, by step four, the m = n term is just a_n. Thus, the whole sum equals a_n.

Comment: " when m = n, we're just dealing with one term of the sum " .. How is that ?
I am sorry , i am not getting it.. :| @user271157

Comment: Got it.. Thank u so much !